# How to deploy a python client script on heroku?

Tags: python, heroku

Basically, I have a python script which using python-twitter api fetches tweets particular hashtag and store it in a database. Script doess this after every 30 seconds. How do i deploy the script to run it on heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a "worker" process type in your Procfile that invokes your script.